# unable to set parameters when context out from webhook - api.ai

Tags: javascript, artificial-intelligence, chatbot, dialogflow-es

**I'm working with** a quiz chatbot, 
first it will ask user for his name, roll number and passcode,
then start asking quiz questions one by one

**problem is** when i'm doing context out from webhook with some parameters, what i want to set is question index
when i'm doing context out after authentication i will set question index to zero, and then increment it on every quiz question, i want to keep track on what question user is with questionIndex parameter

**context out from webhook(code snippet):**

```
var fulfilment = {
    speech: "you are authenticated, say start quiz to start",
    contextOut: [
        {
            "name": "input-name-rollnumber",
            "lifespan": 0,
        },
        {
            "name": "quiz",
            "lifespan": 10,
            "parameters": {
                "questionIndex": 0,
                "name": "inzi"
            }
        }
    ]
}
console.log("response: ", fulfilment);
response.json(fulfilment);
```

after sending context out from webhook, api.ai screen is here:

[image]

**view json of api.ai screen:**
[image]

then if i said "yes start quiz", it goes to server I'm not getting that parameters there

**have a look of webhook: (here i want to increment in question index and send it back for another question)**

[image]

**api.ai screen:**
[image]

**api.ai screen json: **
[image]

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)